# Audio on Gstreamer command

Tags: gstreamer

This command convert rtmp to ts file, but return only video, how can i get audio and video?

```
rtmpsrc name=rtmpsrc location=rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/test ! flvdemux name=demux demux.video ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! multifilesink location=/folder/to/save/%05d.ts sync=true next-file=key-unit-event post-messages=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need anotherbranch `demux.audio ! ... ! mux.`. You can just append this to the end. Use an appropriate parser instead of the ....